building the value attribute of an option tag using jQuery
I have a function like this where I'm dynamically generating the option tag of a select.
function colorInfo(data) {
    console.log("Color Info");
    console.log(data);
    let colorData = JSON.parse(data);

    console.log(colorData);

    $.each(colorData, function (key, value) {
        $("#lineupColors").append(
        $("<option></option>")
           .attr("value",'{"colorId":'+value.colorId+',"colorCode":'+value.colorCode+'}')
          .text(value.colorName)
      );
    });
  }

Since I am defining the value as a Json object, how can I add double quotes such that the value would look like {"colorId":"1","colorCode":"#FFFFFF"}.
Right now it is coming out like this - which is not a valid JSON :
{"colorId":1,"colorCode":#FFFFFF}.

.attr('value', JSON.stringify(yourObject)) where yourObject = {"colorId":"1","colorCode":"#FFFFFF"}

So, something like this   .attr("value",'{"colorId":'+JSON.stringify(value.colorId)+',"colorCode":'+JSON.stringify(value.colorCode)+'}') ?

Since I'm building this part {"colorId":"1","colorCode":"#FFFFFF"}, I am back to my original question as how to add double quotes to make yourObject as a valid JSON.

i'll elaborate with an answer

Need to set the JSON.stringify(object) as the attribute. See example how to manipulate the "input" object.


function colorInfo(data) {
  console.log("Color Info");
  console.log(data);
  let colorData = JSON.parse(data);

  console.log(colorData);

  $.each(colorData, function(key, value) {

    const yourObject = {
      colorId: value.colorId,
      colorCode: value.colorCode
    }

    // you can even set by property name
    var key = "colorCode"
    yourObject[key] = value.colorCode

    // once object is ready to serialize:
    $("#lineupColors").append(
      $("<option></option>")
      .attr("value", JSON.stringify(yourObject))
      .text(value.colorName)
    );
  });
}

colorInfo(JSON.stringify([{
    colorId: 12,
    colorCode: "black",
    colorName: "jonnie",
  },
  {
    colorId: 132,
    colorCode: "#ff0",
    colorName: "yellow"
  }
]));
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="lineupColors">
</select>




Thanks. In order to retrieve the colorId and colorCode for my usage in the code, I had to JSON parse selectedColorId like this: let selectedColorId = $("#lineupColors").val(); , let newSelectedColorId = JSON.parse(selectedColorId); and then access it like this  console.log(newSelectedColorId.colorId); . Same with colorName as well.
